# I know the answer, but I do not see how to answer the specific question?

Tags: discussion

Sorry, this question is about answers. 
I would like to answer the question:
[Make a momentary switch control a toggle](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4060/make-a-momentary-switch-control-a-toggle)
Please, help.
Thank you.

Comment: *"This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site."*  That pretty much explains it.

Comment: Do you really have anything to add to that six year old question?

Comment: It simply struck me the *cheapest* circuit was exceedingly complex and not clear enough. It has 4 transistors and 8 resistors. I can easily draw (and build, of course) a 2-transistor, 4 resistor, and 1 capacitor circuit with the same functionality. Or with 2 MOSFETs, which is better. Enough to control a CMOS circuit. Actually, a simple flip-flop. Well, a third MOSFET can be added if a heavy load required. I wanted to add my answer and send the page to my son to see all the options. Frankly, I myself found a lot of useful things in that *6-year old* page :)

Comment: @Benkevitch that would be great to see. Is there no other question you can find that you can **properly** answer, or **good** question you want to ask first, to gain the rep needed?

Answer (score 4):

That question was [protected](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-protected-question-status/), meaning it was locked down to prevent unregistered, new, or low rep users from answering it. Sometimes this is done to prevent spam. Other times its due to people not answering the question correctly:

- attempting to ask another/different question
- asking for clarification aka commenting
- just general non-answer nonsense like

  - saying ***thanks***
  - saying ***I have this problem too, has anyone found a solution yet?***.

Diamond Moderators, and users with sufficient rep (15,000) have the [Protect Questions privilege.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions). You gain the ability to post on protected questions at 10 rep, gaining the [Remove New User Restrictions privilege.](http://Remove%20New%20User%20Restrictions)

10 rep can be gained by answering a non-protected question and getting at least 1 upvote or asking a question that's upvoted twice. You have to make some worthwhile contributions to the site to gain reputation. Then you can answer that question.

Comment: According to the user profile, that user already has some rep on main StackOverflow site... wonder why they did not get the 100 point "Association Bonus" for joining a second SE site. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: @marku that wouldn't matter anyway, association bonus is ignored for these privileges.

Comment: I'd just like to add that it's a shame @Benkevitch never earned that 10 rep and answered the question. They seemed like a bright person that could contribute much.

Answer (score -4):

The process of providing an answer is very simple.

1) Type your answer in the box labelled (rather obviously) "Your Answer". You will see the final appearance of your answer displayed below the box.

2) Click on the button below the displayed text labelled "Post Your Answer".

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Nope, this is wrong.

Comment: OP has no rep, on a question that has been protected. They can't answer it.